# Mefarshim on Avos d'Rebbi Nassan?

Tags: product-recommendation, commentaries, avot-derabbi-natan

Are there any popular mefarshim on Avos d'Rebbi Nassan not brought down in the standard Vilna Shas (i.e. not Tomas Yesharim or Binyan Yehoshua)?

Comment: see sefer kise rachamim of the chidda. very interesting pshat and yiunim

Comment: @kouty [This](http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/37376)?

Comment: yes @DonielF 3 char

Comment: I wouldn’t consider [this](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/14006) one popular but it’s a nice commentary (focusing also on the Gra’s annotations). More popular is Solomon Schechter’s edition [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/38247). His notes [to both versions of the ADRN] often comprise a literal commentary. As you probably already know, Artscroll recently published their own edition too.